# PHP framework that can be included in other projects

Tags: php, frameworks, include, require, projects

I have a little specific concern, I hope you can help me, I have to develop an application in PHP that doesn't need to be linked to the exclusive use of its installation and could be used or "included" in other projects of PHP, I mean, to develop a web application (such as generation of a graph according to certain parameters passed) that can be used on different pages created for example in phpBB, Drupal, Dreamweaver or PHP Frameworks like CodeIgniter and Zend.

The best example of what I mean is "Google Charts Tools", you just print in the browser the access to the tool with the parameters and the tool does the rest, and this does not depend on the type of framework with which the home page was created.

In short, I'm looking for a framework or lightweight framework with which I can develop an application that simply could be called in an `include()` or `require()` on the destination page and can be used, a framework that can somehow "export" the project or application and could be used on one page without having to reinstall the framework on the target server, even the libraries could be included in the target page so you can run the application.

Was working with Codeigniter and tried to attach to a Joomla page but i couldn't because Codeigniter is linked to the URL of the page and I dont want to use Iframes.

Is there something like that?

Comment: You're not looking for a framework then, but utility libraries (which are often mislabeled micro frameworks). And then it depends on which features you need.

Comment: Next to what mario highlighted, you're also looking for remote access to it or more generally you're looking how to create a *remove service* which can be done in many different ways.

Comment: Ho thank you everyone I was searching in deep about the Micro Frameworks, I learned a couple of them and it was what i was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to write a *library* or *class* that can do certain things and which can be reused in other code. You can then build an *example application* around it, using a framework, which uses this library.

If you start with a whole *framework*, this often makes it really hard to reuse any part of the code, since the framework has certain assumptions or requirements which may not always be true for other projects. As a general rule: a framework is already a complete standalone application. What you want is something smaller than that.

Of course, you can have a look at a framework like Zend, which is basically just a loose collection of individual classes. Together they form a framework, but each part of it is individually usable. Something like CI is on the other end of the spectrum, much more heavily coupled and interdependent.

Answer (score 1):

First of all; I believe you would need some custimization, as frameworks just aren't build that way. But it isn't impossible. In [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) for example (also codeigniter, but kohana is more flexible), you can build internal requests with `Request::factory($uri)`. If you can find out a way to bypass direct access to index.php, or build a wrapper after which you can do stuff in the Kohana 'environment' you could do it. I don't have a ready-to-use solution, but if you try something and post the code we might be able to help you out some more!